# pdf option for pstricks conflicts with babel french option

Tags: pstricks, babel, incompatibility

Today I had this error message on compiling a document:

```
! Package babel Error: The character '"' is not a shorthand character in french
```

After commenting a lot of things I finally identified the culprit: Using the `pdf` option with `pstricks`. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf, pstricks}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}

\psset{xunit = 0.5cm, plotstyle = curve}
\begin{pspicture}(-10,-1)(10,2)
\psaxes[labels=none]{->}(0,0)(-10,-1)(10,2)%
\psplot[linecolor=blue,linewidth=1.5pt, algebraic]{-10}{10}{1/(1 + x^2)}%
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Replacing `[french]` with, say, `german` results in no error message.

Same thing if I comment `usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}` and uncomment `\usepackage{autopst-pdf,pstricks}`.

Is there something to be done?

Another question about the `pdf` option of `pstricks`: Packages like `pst-plot` or `pstricks-add` load `pstricks`; why don't they pass the `pdf` option on to `pstricks`? For  most of my work, I only have to load `pstricks-add`. If I want to use this option I also have to explicitly write `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}` first.

Comment: as an aside, the `x^2` from your code appears on this site as a unicode upperscript `2`, and testing the code necessitates rewriting it as  `x^2`.

Answer (score 4):

there are some problems if `pstricks` is loaded before `auto-pst-pdf`. Use

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
[...]
```

Comment: Yes, I didn't take care of that. But the main problem is that I don't have to load auto-pst-pdf if I use the pdf option, and that conflicts with the french option of babel. The commented line with auto-pst-pdf is there only to ease comparing the different ways to do things.

Comment: the `pdf` option does nothing else than loading `auto-pst-pdf`, but in this case too late.

Comment: OK, I see. But why does directly loading auto-pst-pdf not conflict with french, and using the pdf option of pstricks does?

Comment: As I already wrote: With `[pdf]` the `pstricks.sty` package is loaded first and then `auto-pst-pdf`

Comment: @Herbert Is this conflict documented somewhere in `pstricks-add` or `pstricks` ? Ignorant Q: Is it good idea to add [pdf] option for other pstricks addons `pst-plot`,`pstricks-add`.

Comment: @texenthusiast: The problem wasn't known and `[pdf]` will not be added to the other packages.